# How do I restrict mime types on files uploaded through a WFFM form in MVC?

Tags: wffm, mvc, rules-engine

I am looking for a way to restrict MIME Types on files uploaded through a WFFM form. What I am really hoping for is a way to control the allowed MIME Types using the rules engine. Even if the solution doesn't use the rules engine, it may still help and is still welcome.

**Update:** We are using our own custom File Upload field that inherits from the OOTB one. I would prefer to not have to rewrite or modify this field for this solution to work, but I will if I absolutely must.

I am using Sitecore 8.1u2 and WFFM 8.1.160304 in an MVC solution.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/10/06/sitecore-marketplace-module-secure-file-upload/ ?

Comment: I have. The only problem with the module is that it requires that I use the included "Secure File Upload" field. We actually have our own custom File Upload field that I would prefer to not rewrite.

Comment: Here is a nice solution using validation https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/04/06/restrict-certain-files-from-being-attached-to-web-forms-for-marketers-forms-in-sitecore/

Comment: Post it as an answer and give a little summary :)

Answer (score 3):

I know that you are looking for a way to do it via the Rules Engine. However, you can do it with a custom field validator.

You can restrict the MIME types that are passed to the custom validator through a parameter named `MimeTypesNotAllowed`, and these are injected into a property of the same name and map them in Sitecore.

Take a look at https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/04/06/restrict-certain-files-from-being-attached-to-web-forms-for-marketers-forms-in-sitecore/

Comment: Thanks!let me know if you run into issues by opening a NTT quest.

Comment: Does the suggestion above by @CSigmon applicable to Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 and WFFM 8.1 160523 ? I've tried it and it seems not working on my end.